# How to init a UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview

In my main viewController, I have this:

```
// .h
#import "YNSlidingMenu.h"

@interface YNAddNoteViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) YNSlidingMenu *slidingMenu;
@end

// .m
- (void)setUpSlidingMenu{
    _slidingMenu = [[YNSlidingMenu alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:_slidingMenu];
}
```

In YNSlidingMenu.m, I have this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self configureView];
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"init");
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)configureView{
    NSLog(@"configureView");
    self.rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 40);
}
```

YNSlidingMenu will get its frame for itself based on its contents, so I don't want to init it on my viewController with `initWithFrame`.

What do I need to do? `NSLog(@"init");` doesn't get called. How can I initialize my custom view without setting the frame from my viewController?

Comment: Does `- setUpSlidingMenu` get called from somewhere?

Comment: In YNSlidingMenu's `initWithFrame:` add a breakpoint or `NSLog()` to see if it is getting called and if so what the frame is. You should do the same thing in view controller's `setUpSlidingMenu` to make sure it is getting called.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can get its frame base on its content, unless of cause you're using auto layout.
A proper approach is that you init you view with `CGRectZero`. Then set the frame latter when you are ready.
Or you can adopting auto layout.

Comment: I did, and it worked. However, I don't know why that approach seems a little dirty, IMO.

Comment: I just never seem it in non-autolayout code, but basically it's the same as `initWithFrame:CGRectZero`... guess there is some function forwarding in `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

Move [self configureView] out of your initWithFrame: method and into your init method as your calling init when you initialize your view. At least that's what your sample code looks like.

Comment: I did, and it still doesn't get called.

Comment: Where in your controller are you calling setUpSlidingView?

Comment: viewDidLoad, on my main viewController.

Comment: Change the X and Y coordinates to something larger as a test. It might be hidden under a UINavigationController or some other view.